# C realloc() Invalid Pointer Error even though malloc was used

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays, realloc

I have a dynamic array implementation I'm working on for generic types. My understanding is that the invalid pointer error for realloc is usually caused by not using malloc to allocate the original pointer, however, I am using malloc.

Here is my array.h code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct array {
    void *elems;
    size_t obj_size;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
};

struct array* new_array(size_t objsize);
int push_back(struct array* a, const void* value);
```

Array.c

```
#include "array.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define INITIAL_SIZE (1)
#define ARR_AT(a, i) ((void *) ((char *) (a)->elems + (i) * (a)->obj_size))

struct array* new_array(size_t objsize) {
    struct array* a;

    a = malloc(sizeof a + INITIAL_SIZE * objsize);
    if (!a) { return NULL; }

    a->elems = malloc(objsize);
    a->capacity = 1;
    a->size = 0;
    return a;
}

int push_back(struct array* a, const void* value) {
    if (a->size == a->capacity) {
        void* temp = realloc(a->elems, a->obj_size * a->capacity * 2); 
        a->elems = temp;
        if (!a) { return -1; }
        a->capacity = a->capacity * 2;
    }

    memcpy(ARR_AT(a, a->size), value, a->obj_size);
    a->size++;
    return 0;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "array.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    struct array* a = new_array(4);
    uint32_t* b = (uint32_t*) 3;
    push_back(a, b);
    printf("Size: %ld \n", a->size);

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        push_back(a, b + i);
        printf("Size: %ld \n", a->size);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I've been trying to fix this error, but my C skills are subpar. What am I missing here?

Comment: `a->obj_size` is never set so the `realloc` is probably failing due to invalid size. Which you also would not catch as you are checking the wrong pointer: `if (!a)` should be `if (!temp)` or `if (!a->elems)`

Comment: Oh gosh, what a dumb mistake. Thank you.

Comment: `realloc()` fails also, if the requested space cannot be allocated. Your program needs to save the old pointer, because it is not freed in that case.

Comment: If you make use of a debugger (like gdb) then the problem displays itself within minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `malloc` is wrong:

```
a = malloc(sizeof a + INITIAL_SIZE * objsize);
           \------/   \----------------------/
       sizeof pointer     some extra bytes
```

This does **not** allocate space for a `struct array`. It allocates memory corresponding to the size of a pointer and some extra bytes (here 1*4).

On my system the above allocation is for 12 bytes but `struct array` requires 32 bytes.

So the allocated memory can't hold a `struct array` and you are accessing memory that isn't assigned to you. Then anything may happen.

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve with this `malloc`. The "normal way" is simply:

```
a = malloc(sizeof *a); // Allocate a single 'struct array'
```

And you also need to save `objsize` like

```
a->obj_size = objsize;
```

in the `new_array` function. If you don't the `realloc` uses an uninitialized variable:

```
realloc(a->elems, a->obj_size * a->capacity * 2);
                  \---------/
                   Currently uninitialized
```

Further this is very strange:

```
uint32_t* b = (uint32_t*) 3;  // Converting the number 3 to a pointer !?
push_back(a, b);              // and then push_back uses that pointer
                              // in memcpy... that has to fail...
```

I wonder if you really want something like:

```
uint32_t b = 3;   // Make an ordinary uint variable with value 3
push_back(a, &b); // Pass a pointer to the variable b so that
                  // the raw data representing the value 3 can be
                  // copied to "struct array"->elems
```

As a final note:

Sometimes you check for NULL after `malloc` and sometimes you don't. Either do it every time or don't do it at all.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, so I noticed that malloc issue after posting and fixed it. What I actually wanted is what you listed and I wanted a->elems to be malloc(objsize * INITIAL_SIZE).

For the uint32_t cast, yes I'm dumb. I am using other code as a reference to try and learn. That code is meant to be passed a struct with an address, not a value. I'm still wondering if there is a way to pass in normal ints, chars, etc. I guess I wanted this to work no matter what type you passed to the function.

I'm marking this as the correct answer. The comment someone left about realloc() was also correct.

Comment: @SeanPayne See update re calling `push_back`. Maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Thank you. Sorry about that. The type casting is so confusing coming from Python. I've been spoon fed too much :(

Comment: @SeanPayne Well... Python is very confusing when coming from C. ;-)

Comment: @SeanPayne To be more serious about casting... yes, casting is a bit complex. However, the good thing is that you don't need casting in ordinary well-designed programs. It's only when doing advanced stuff that casting is needed. BTW: If you want to look into the complexicity of casting (and pointer handling) then reading about "strict aliasing".